# Is there any other AWS method like cognito that I can use to login other than AWS cognito in kotlin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using AWS appsync and I will also use AWS for login. By the way, I am not very familiar with AWS, so forgive me if I use the wrong term. There is an AWS cognito method for user login and cognito wants me to implement something called amplifier and it wants a secret key.

The questions I want to ask here are these. According to my research, implementing Amplify is a difficult and tedious job and the secret key should be secret, it tells me to use it, but I do not want to use this secret key, that is, I do not want to do it without using it. Is there a way to log in to AWS without using amplify and secret key?

Comment: You do not need to use amplify for AWS Development . Are you using the new AWS SDK for Kotlin?

Comment: Can you point me to the doc that stated you need to use Amplify please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in my comment, you do not need to use Amplify to interact with AWS Services using Kotlin. You should be using **AWS SDK for Kotlin**.

[What is the AWS SDK for Kotlin?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/home.html)

Using the SDK, you can build Kotlin applications that work with Amazon S3, Amazon EC2, Amazon DynamoDB, and so on. With the Kotlin SDK, you can target the JVM platform or Android API level 24 or higher. This SDK Supports Kotlin features like [Coroutines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/coroutines.html).

Now to use this, you still need to use your AWS credentials as described in the DEV GUide here:

[Credentials providers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/credential-providers.html)

You can find Kotlin code examples for many AWS Services here:

[Code examples for SDK for Kotlin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/kotlin_1_code_examples.html)

To get up and running with the Kotlin SDK, start here:

[Set up the AWS SDK for Kotlin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/setup.html)